# Race condition between componentWillReceiveProps and componentDidMount

Tags: ajax, reactjs

I have a component that takes some data in the props and make an ajax request with them.

```
var ItemList = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        filters: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    },
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {items: []};
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.ajaxFetchItems(this.props.filters);
    },
    componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
        this.ajaxFetchItems(nextProps.filters);
    },
    ajaxFetchItems: function(filter) {
        ....
        this.setState({items: data});
    }
}
```

The problem is that the props are changed almost immediately, and sometimes the ajax call in `componentDidMount` is slightly slower than the one in `componentWillReceiveProps`, so the initial state is written after the first update.

How can I avoid that a slow componentDidMount will overwrite a fast componentWillReceiveProps?

There are better ways to handle the lifecycle of a react component that downloads its data?

Comment: only fetch if the next `filters` prop is different from the current one

Comment: I try to avoid having application logic within the application tree - so in this case I'd apply the filters to a store and tell it to reload, any my component would be listening for changes to the store and would update once it has finished loading. If you wanted you could only update the store if new_filters !== old_filters which would mean that if 2 ajaxFetchItems fire in quick succession it's a no-op.

Or you could use a debounce on the storeload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put a timestamp in state for the latest update processed.
And somehow make sure that the timestamp of the original Ajax request is included in the Ajax results.

And add a `shouldComponentUpdate()` to check if the received results have a timestamp that is later than the timestamp in state. If not: return false, and your component will ignore the results.

By the way: `componentDidMount` and `componentWillReceiveProps` can by definition only be run in that order. I suspect that your first Ajax call takes long to return result, and your second call is fast. So you get the Ajax results back in the wrong order.
(Not due to slow react functions).

UPDATE:
Using shouldComponentUpdate is the react-way of dealing with this case: Its purpose is to allow for comparison of the new state with the old state, and based on that comparison, not rerender.

The issue is (most likely) generated by the order in which ajax responses come in:

1. Ajax call 1 (fired in componentDidMount in this example)
2. Ajax call 2 (fired in componentWillReceiveProps, trigger by parent of component)
3. Response from call 2 comes in
4. Response from call 1 comes in.

So a more generic question/ solution would be for "How to handle ajax responses coming back in the wrong order".

The timestamp (in shouldComponentUpdate) is one way to do it.

An alternative (described [here](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/04/03/strategies-for-dealing-with-multiple-ajax-calls)) is to make the second request (in componentWillReceiveProps) abort the first ajax request.

**Revisit:**
After giving it some further thought (the calls in componentDidMount and componentWillReceiveProps did not feel right), a more general react-like way to approach your component would probably be as follows:

Your component's job is basically to:

- receive filter via prop,
- use filter to fetch list with ajax,
- and render ajax reponse = list.

So it has 2 inputs:

- filter (= prop)
- list (= ajax response)

and only 1 output = list (which may be empty).

Workings:

- The first time component receives filter as prop: it needs to send out ajax request, and render an empty list or some loading state.
- all subsequent filters: component should send out a new ajax request (and kill possible outstanding old requests), **and it should NOT re-render (!)**.
- whenever it receives an ajax response, it should re-render the list (by updating state).

Setting this up with react would probably look something like this:

```
getInitialState() {
  this.fetchAjax(this.props.filter);            // initiate first ajax call here
  return { list : [] };                         // used to maybe display "loading.." message
}
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  this.fetchAjax(nextProps.filter);            // send off ajax call to get new list with new filter
}
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  return (this.state.list != nextState.list);   // only update component if there is a new list
                                                // so when new props (filter) comes in there is NO rerender
}
render() {
  createChildrenWith(this.state.list);
}
fetchAjax(filter) {
  killOutStandingRequests();                    // some procedure to kill old ajax requests
  getListAsync…
    request: filter                             // request new list with new filter
    responseHandler: this.handleResponse        // add responseHandler
}
responseHandler(data) {
  this.setState({ list : data });               // put the new list in state, triggering render
}
```

The original timestamp in state would solve the question posted above, but I thought I'd share the revised react component as a bonus...

Comment: Yes, surely is the ajax call that takes too long, I was not so clear.
You solution could work, but there aren't more idiomatic ways? It seems to me a so common example..

Comment: I think shouldComponentUpdate (with timestamp) is the react-way to solve this issue. Other generic solutions are also possible, e.g. using promises, or by making the second request kill the first request. I provided a link to generic javascript solution in the updated answer.

Comment: I added a generic cleaned up react component to the answer. Goes beyond your original question, but might help nonetheless.